# Problem with react aplication hosting in IIS server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sql-server, express, axios

I am hosting a React application on IIS server it is rendering other PC also. But backend is built with NodeJS express and SQL Server using API axios but data is not getting to other PCs. When I am trying on my PC, it is ok, data is dynamically changing as per my request. This is my first site hosting please help me to resolve it

How to get backend data on other PC along with the react?

Answer (score 0):

Just build your React source and run the built source with xamp
[image]

1. Open `Explorer` folder in `Xamp`
2. In opened window find `htdocs` folder and Pase built source at there
3. Go to xamp app and click on `Start` for `Apache`

[image]

Now in other pc's browser write Serve's ip to execute your app